# Water level indicator LEDs one by one

Tags: transistors, led, water

I want to make a water level indicator but, instead of all LEDs lighting at 100% (for example) I want the top one only to light and the rest turn off

- at 0% all LEDs off
- at 25% the first LED on
- at 50% the first LED of and the second on
- at 75% the second and first LED s off and the third on
- at 100% only the fourth LED  on.

I tried this circuit but it did not work with water.

[image]

Comment: (1) Please post a better quality image with the grid turned off. (2) "*I tried this circuit but it did not work with water.*" Did it work when you closed the switches? If not, what did it do and what did it not do? (3) What kind of water? Distilled, de-ionised, tap water, salt water? Please use the [edit] link to clarify.

Comment: I do not how to post a new image, how can I do it?

Comment: Where did you get the image? If you drew it yourself then take a higher resolution screengrab. If not then you probably can't improve it but you need to add a credit and link to the original author. (This is site policy.)

Comment: I have a better resolution one, My problem is how to post an image to this form

Comment: Hit "Edit" under your question.  Delete the existing image, insert the new one.

Comment: okay Will do it now thanks

Comment: "Did not work with water." Are you using float switches, or water conductivity sensors, or something else?  What do the switches really represent?

Comment: no just bare wires from transistor base into the water

Comment: @Seif_1999 If you plan on using BJTs for water level detection then you will need a high impedance input. This can be done with two BJTs and MOhm resistors. But I've designed units for detecting water around toilets before and this isn't a matter of just sticking a BJT base into water. That much I know for sure. And please say something about the water (salty, etc) and about the container (shape) and how you imagine building up the sensor. Also, you have % given, but we'd need ranges not exact numbers.

Comment: It is tap water, so I assume low conductivity but certainly higher than distilled water. The container is cylindrical, but I am testing with a small bottle. About building the sensor I thought I would just stick bare wires at different levels in the container, but this does not seem to work. This approach works for me if the each LED lights and keeps on even when the next LED light (each transistor wired separately as a switch independent from other transistors)

Answer (score 0):

An optical prism water sensor is 'on' by default (dry) and 'off' when immersed. Sounds like exactly what you're looking for, and you avoid the hassle of passing electricity through water.

More about those here: https://www.electroschematics.com/optical-liquid-level-sensor/

You could literally just wire LEDs to the phototransistors and get the effect you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a first draft of a solution using N-MOSFETS. Each one turning off the previous one.
SW1 to 4 are float switches. Only the float switches are in the water.

Capacitors should be between 0.1uF and 1uF (test before deciding). Capacitor voltage no less than 25V.

Schottky Diodes prevent current dropped by the LED's to reach the previous MOSFET gate. (update)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvqUYI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Beat me by 3 minutes. I went and measured the water resistance in a glass before hitting "Add".

Comment: This circuit has a logic issue.  When SW4 closes, M4 turns off M3, which allows M1 to come back on.  The same thing happens with SW5.  Diodes.

Comment: Also, with 10 K LED resistors, current is only around 1 mA.

Comment: @AnalogKid Indeed. I added some diodes. I think it will solve this issue. Of course Led resistors can be reduced to increase intensity.

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem with the original circuit (besides a schematic that is difficult to decipher) is that water resistance is too high.  The schematic doesn't say what the operating voltage is, but the water resistance could be a few hundred K ohms.  This will not allow enough current through to saturate two transistors with collector currents in the 10's of mA.

One possible solution is to change all of the transistors to small-signal n-channel MOSFETs.  Add a 1 M resistor from each gate to GND.  While you're at it, I think you can replace three of the transistors with 6 diodes.

Comment: Using the conductivity of water will not be reliable. Moisture and droplets could trigger the signal. You definitely need mechanical switches.

Comment: @Fredled Mechanical switches—such as float switches—can fail due to fouling, especially with hard water, in just a few months.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Yes, there is no safe solution and various solutions exist. It really depends on the type of water and the type of tanks and on the environment. But using water conductivity is a no go if you ask me.

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is three years old, but it has some recent activity, so . . . here.

As a public service for future generations, here is the OP schematic redrawn for clarity.  The structure of the circuit is fine.  It is not clear why the LED resistors are split into two resistors with the bypass transistor connected in the middle.  The circuit would work fine and have much less power dissipation if the bypass transistor were connected directly to the LED anode, and the two resistors combined into a single 300 ohm part.

Operation is straightforward.  Each switch closes successively as the water level rises.  As each switch closes, one transistor lights its own LED and another transistor bypasses the previous stage's LED, turning it off.

[image]

Each switch represents two probe wires maybe 1/2" apart.  When water rises to their level, it appears as a resistance between the probe wires.  The only real problem with this circuit is that water resistance is too high to drive a bipolar transistor, let alone two in parallel.  To barely saturate both transistors would require a water resistance of 18K or less, while real water could be several hundred K.

Using a second transistor to inhibit the previous stage LED rather than the previous stage driver works well, and is in fact less complex that using steering diodes.

---

As above, the only real problem is the inadequate drive current caused by the high resistance water.  A solution is to change the transistors to small-signal n-channel MOSFETs.  Here is a reworked schematic with FETs.  This version also replaces the bypass transistors with diodes.  A diode is able to bypass an LED because while the LED's forward voltage (Vf) is around 2 V or more, a signal diode Vf is around 0.7 V.  The diode clamps the LED's anode at a voltage too low for it to conduct and illuminate.

With this approach, even a water resistance of 1 M would still present a gate voltage of 6 V, more than enough to "saturate" (fully enhance) the FET.

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to use AC across the level sensors to reduce corrosion of the contacts? It seems likely that the indicator LEDs do not need to be on at 100% duty cycle.

Comment: Certainly possible, but that is a much more complex design.  The original question was about why his circuit did not work correctly.

Answer (score -2):

This can be achieved fairly easily with the help of a microcontroller and a bit of code.

You can use an Arduino which is quite easy to start with.

Connect each Led to a pin of the Arduino and use what is called a PWM to vary their frequency.

Connect your sensors likewise to other input pins.

There are tons of example on Google on how to achieve that, they keyword is LED PWM control Arduino.

Comment: I intended to do it without a microcontroller, but thank you any way

Comment: @Seif_1999 any reason why not using a microcontroller?

Comment: @Damien Why would you want to use an Arduino and PWM for a project as simple as this? Makes no sens to me.

Answer (score -3):

The best way you can do it is by a digital circuit. Create the truth table , do the K-maps required and find the boolean expression of the circuit and use **digital** logic gates.

It so much easier to do it using digital circuits than analog circuit because in the end if you try to do it with a analog circuit you will end up building digital logic gates  , dont reinvent the wheel!

Comment: so it is not possible to do it with just transistors?

Comment: If you try build it with transistors you can do it but it will take much more time and as I said you will end up building the logic gates from transistors which isn't worth the effort.

Comment: @MissMulan:  I think you miss a very large part of the problem.  Aside from the logic, the circuit is supposed to detect the level of water - but doesn't because it uses switches instead of some kind of water detection.  You've got a suggestion for solving the last bit of it (the display,)  but nothing on the detection side.

Comment: @JRE  the inputs will be from a device which converts pressure to voltage i am not sure why I should say that.

Comment: Well, that's important.  See, I expected water conductivity sensors to be used rather than pressure sensors.  Maybe someone else expects float switches.

Comment: It is also possible to solve  this using comparators - fully analog.

Comment: Comparators have digital output they are not analog

Comment: What about the **inputs** of a comparator? Are you going to say those are digital, too? A comparator **is analog**.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson comparators are hybrid devices

Comment: Without getting into specialty devices, a generic comparator is a linear amplifier with lotsa forward gain, little or no compensation, and no negative feedback.  And often (but not always) missing one output transistor.  If you replace the missing transistor with a resistor and add negative feedback, you get an opamp with a class-A output stage.  Relatively noisy, but zero crossover distortion.

Comment: I challenge miss mulan to work up the circuit using nothing but AND, OR, NAND, and NOR gates, and count the number of pins that have to be soldered.  For a one-off project, this is an excellent way to compare different circuit approaches.

Comment: It's perfectly doable with logic gates. I would recommend logic gates for any complex logic processing, (but not as complex as to use a micro controller). However Miss Mulan doesn't answer the question. You only suggest a method. This would be better as a comment than an answer.